# Macos always change the command "TeX-view-program-list" into ""open %o" in emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, auctex, okular

In custom.el I set as follows.

```
'(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular --unique %o#src:%n%b"))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Okular"))))
```

Also I aliased the okular in zsh.
`alias okular="/Applications/MacPorts/KDE4/okular.app/Contents/MacOS/okular"`

But each time I want to view. The command becomes "open ......"

And I got to see the custom varible. It shows as follows
[image]

How can I deal with it?
Thank you very much.

**Update:2015-10-31**
I find reason, I use bbatsov/prelude configuration. In his module,prelude-latex.el, he define the default viewer, so that I can't change. Now I comment it and everything's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `custom.el` is being loaded?  Perhaps you set `custom-file`, but forgot to `load` it?

Also, I don't think that aliasing it will work, because Emacs is looking for an executable, but aliases are specific to the shell.

Comment: In my *Message*. It shows "Loading /Users/****/.emacs.d/personal/custom.el (source)...done". So emacs read the file. Maybe the reason, as you said, I alias a file in the /Application/ folder, it can't read.  And then it use default values.

Comment: I find reason, I use bbatsov/prelude configuration. In his module,prelude-latex.el, he define the default viewer, so that I can't change. Now I comment it and everything's ok.